# The order statistics of uniform distribution $U_{n,{k_n}}$ times $n$ tends to $\infty$ in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $U_1,U_2,...U_n,$ be iid samples from uniform distribution $U(0,1)$. And the order Statistic:
\begin{equation}
U_{n,1}\leq U_{n,2}\leq ...\leq U_{n,n},
\end{equation}

Let $1\leq k_n \leq n$ and $k_n\rightarrow\infty$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Proof: $Y_n=nU_{n,{k_n}} \rightarrow \infty$ in probability, i.e. for every $M>0$,
\begin{equation}
lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \quad P(Y_n>M)=1
\end{equation}

My ideas so far:
The density function of $U_{n,k_n}$ is
\begin{equation}
f_U(x)=\frac{n!}{(k_n-1)!(n-k_n)!}x^{k_n-1}(1-x)^{n-k_n}.
\end{equation}
And the density function of $Y_n=nU_{n,k_n}$ is
\begin{equation}
f_Y(x)=\frac{(n-1)!}{(k_n-1)!(n-k_n)!}(\frac{x}{n})^{k_n-1}(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n-k_n}.
\end{equation}
But the integral
\begin{equation}
P(Y_n>M)=\int_{M}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)!}{(k_n-1)!(n-k_n)!}(\frac{x}{n})^{k_n-1}(1-\frac{x}{n})^{n-k_n}dx.
\end{equation}
seems very complicated, what can I do next?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $U_{n,k}$ has the same distribution as $S_k/S_{n+1}$, where
$$
S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n v_i, \quad v_i\overset{\text{iid}}{=}\text{Exp}(1).
$$
Thus, for any $M<\infty$,
$$
\mathsf{P}\!\left(nU_{n,k_n}>M\right)=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\frac{n}{S_{n+1}}\cdot S_{k_n}>M\right)\to 1
$$
as $n\to\infty$ because $S_{n+1}/n\to 1$ a.s. and $S_{k_n}\to \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Thanks for your help again! Could you please provide a slightly proof of  why $U_{n,k}$ has the same distribution as $S_k/S_{n+1}$?

Comment: The joint pdf of $v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}$ is $\exp(-(y_1+\ldots+y_{n+1}))$, $y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}\ge 0$. Thus, using the transformation
$$
(y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1})\mapsto \left(\frac{y_1}{y_1+\cdots+y_{n+1}},\frac{y_1+y_2}{y_1+\cdots+y_{n+1}},\ldots,y_1+\cdots y_{n+1}\right),
$$
the joint pdf of $(S_1/S_{n+1},\ldots,S_n/S_{n+1},S_{n+1})$ is given by
$$
f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1})=x_{n+1}^n \exp(x_{n+1}), \quad 0\le x_1\le \cdots\le x_n,x_{n+1}\ge 0.
$$
Finally, integrating $f$ w.r.t. $x_{n+1}$ yields $n!$ on $\{0\le x_1\le \cdots\le x_n\le 1\}$, which is the joint pdf of $U_{n,1},\ldots, U_{n,n}$.

Comment: Thank you ！！！:)